# Requesting information about Windows CE platform for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I cannot find any documentation about what operating systems are supported by the "Windows CE" platform under Visual Studio 2008.

My objective is to develop a C# .NET application for a Windows CE 5.0 (not Windows Mobile 5) device. I inherited a project that had a database back-end developed in Visual Studio 2008 and want to use the same IDE. I had Visual Studio 2005 installed with the Standard Windows CE 5.0 SDK and was able to target a device correctly. After I installed (a side-by-side installation of) Visual Studio 2008, the Windows CE 5.0 target is missing from both VS2008 and VS2005; instead, there is now a platform labeled simply Windows CE.

I've already spent three days trying to figure out how to target a WinCE5 device from VS2008. I even found some references to installing the Standard Windows CE 5.0 SDK using Administrator Privileges for Windows 7, but a co-worker encountered an identical problem for Windows XP.

I would appreciate anybody who could educate me about what Microsoft changed and how to build an application for the correct device type. I've been programming WinCE devices for over a decade and never before run into this level of obfuscation.

Can anyone tell me or direct me to that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important bit of info is that for managed application development **you do not need any SDK**.  Studio has support for a "Windows CE" target, and that is all you need (in fact you can use the "Pocket PC 2003" or any WinMo target and it will still work - the Form designer experience is just not so good.

This is becasue in all cases, the output is MSIL, not a processor-dependent binary.

My recommendation is to not try using ActiveSync for debugging, just use [a direct CoreCon connection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/archive/2005/04/28/413304.aspx) and you're all set.